# Accessing docker container over https on Azure subdomain

Tags: azure, docker, https, kubernetes

As an experiment I'm trying to run a docker container on Azure using the Azure Container Service and Kubernetes as the orchestrator. I'm running the official nginx image. Here are the steps I am taking:

`az group create --name test-group --location westus
az acs create --orchestrator-type=kubernetes --resource-group=test-group --name=k8s-cluster --generate-ssh-keys`

I created Kubernetes deployment and service files from a docker compose file using Kompose.

**deployment file**

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.service.type: LoadBalancer
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: test
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:latest
        name: test
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}`

**service file**

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.service.type: LoadBalancer
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: test
  name: test
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: test
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}`

I can then start everything up:

`kubectl create -f test-service.yaml,test-deployment.yaml`

Once an IP has been exposed I assign a dns prefix to it so I can access my running container like so: *http*://nginx-test.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/.

**My question is, how can I access the service using https? At http*s*://nginx-test.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/**

I don't think I'm supposed to configure nginx for https, since the certificate is not mine. I've tried changing the load balancer to send 443 traffic to port 80, but I receive a timeout error.

I tried mapping port 443 to port 80 in my Kubernetes service config.

`ports:
- name: "443"
  port: 443
  targetPort: 80`

But that results in:

`SSL peer was not expecting a handshake message it received. Error code: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_UNEXPECTED_ALERT`

How can I view my running container at https://nginx-test.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/?

Comment: well, your nginx should serve https, not http

Comment: Do I need to bind it to a certificate then?

Comment: obviously you do

Comment: The cert belongs to Microsoft. So are you saying I can't do what I want to?

Comment: which cert, I don't get it? why would the certificate on your nginx belong to ms?

Comment: The domain 'westus.cloudapp.azure.com' is the default domain applications will run under, for resources in 'westus'. I added the prefix 'nginx-test' to my public IP resource. This way I don't have to purchase or setup a domain for experiments. I can use a sub-domain off of the Azure top level domain.

Comment: so? this has nothing to do with the cert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147877/discussion-between-chris-and-4c74356b41).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, I think you are looking for `Nginx Ingress controller`.
If we need TLS termination on Kubernetes, we can use ingress controller, on Azure we can use `Nginx Ingress controller`.
To archive this, we can follow those steps:
1 Deploy the Nginx Ingress controller
2 Create TLS certificates
3 Deploy test http service
4 configure TLS termination
More information about configure Nginx Ingress Controller for TLS termination on Kubernetes on Azure, please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/livedevopsinjapan/2017/02/28/configure-nginx-ingress-controller-for-tls-termination-on-kubernetes-on-azure-2/).

```
root@k8s-master-6F403744-0:~/ingress/examples/deployment/nginx# kubectl get services --namespace kube-system -w
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
default-http-backend   10.0.113.185   <none>        80/TCP    42m
heapster   10.0.4.232   <none>    80/TCP    1h
kube-dns   10.0.0.10   <none>    53/UDP,53/TCP   1h
kubernetes-dashboard   10.0.237.125   <nodes>   80:32229/TCP   1h
nginx-ingress-ssl   10.0.92.57   40.71.37.243   443:30215/TCP   13m
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suppose a self signed cert needs to be involved at some point, there's no getting around that. I was able to follow the blog steps to set it up. Unfortunately I work in an environment which blocks access to the site when using a self signed cert, so I still can't access the site from my internal network. Nevertheless, I'll mark this answer as accepted. Thanks.