# SSL integration Azure docker

Tags: azure, ssl, docker

We have docker swarm container and  would like to enable https to this service. Can anyone tell me how to integrate Windows Azure Docker container service with SSL certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me how to integrate Windows Azure Docker container
>   service with SSL certificate ?

For now, Azure load balancer is a basic Layer 4 (TCP) load balancer, many applications require additional features, so we need **another load balancer**.

If we want to enable SSL 
certificate for ACS swarm, we should use NGINX, the NGINX provides is SSL/TLS termination. Nginx work in this way:
[image]

More information about NGINX load balancer, please refer to this [link](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/ssl-load-balancer/).

Load balancing containers with Docker Swarm and Nginx, please refer to this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/load-balancing-containers-with-docker-swarm-and-ng).

By the way, here a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812199/accessing-docker-container-over-https-on-azure-subdomain/44818751#44818751) about your, but that case talk about K8S, not Swarm, use Nginx to load balancing SSL.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.