# HTTPS with Azure Container Services and Kubernetes

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, containers, azure-container-service

Can anyone show how to setup https on kubernetes in ACS? 
Most tutorials suggest to use LetsEncrypt but does not seem to fit my case as I have an existing .pfx i would like to use.

I created the az acs using the following cli command:

> az acs create --orchestrator-type kubernetes --resource-group
>   myResourceGroup --name myAppName --generate-ssh-keys

and once everything got created i used the following command to spin up my services and deployments

> kubectl create -f myApp.yaml

where myApp.yaml reads as following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myApp-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myApp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myApp
        image: myAppcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/myApp-images:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myAppservice
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: myApp
```

which gets my app working as intended for http:// but I am not too sure what my next steps are to get https:// working. Any helpful links also are appreciated.

P.s. my app is a net core 2.0 hosted in kestrel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we can use **Nginx Ingress Controller** to archive that in ACS.

The Ingress Controller works like this:

[image]

We can follow this steps to do it:

1 Deploy the Nginx Ingress controller
2 Create TLS certificates
3 Deploy test http service
4 configure TLS termination
More information about configure Nginx Ingress Controller for TLS termination on Kubernetes on Azure, please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/livedevopsinjapan/2017/02/28/configure-nginx-ingress-controller-for-tls-termination-on-kubernetes-on-azure-2/).

Here a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812199/accessing-docker-container-over-https-on-azure-subdomain/44818751#44818751), please refer to it.

By the way, here [a example](https://pascalnaber.wordpress.com/2017/10/27/configure-ingress-on-kubernetes-using-azure-container-service/) about configure Ingress on kubernetes using Azure Container service, please refer to it.